# How to get the host name of the current machine as defined in the Ansible hosts file?

Tags: ansible

I'm setting up an Ansible playbook to set up a couple servers. There are a couple of tasks that I only want to run if the current host is my local dev host, named "local" in my hosts file. How can I do this? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

I've tried this when statement, but it fails because `ansible_hostname` resolves to the host name generated when the machine is created, not the one you define in your hosts file.

```yaml
- name: Install this only for local dev machine
  pip: 
    name: pyramid
  when: ansible_hostname == "local"
```

Answer (score 305, accepted):

The necessary variable is [`inventory_hostname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

```yaml
- name: Install this only for local dev machine
  pip: 
    name: pyramid
  when: inventory_hostname == "local"
```

It is somewhat hidden in the documentation [at the bottom of this section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables).

Comment: Variable currently is documented at: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

Answer (score 4):

You can limit the scope of a playbook by changing the hosts header in its plays without relying on your special host label ‘local’ in your inventory. Localhost does not need a special line in inventories.

```
- name: run on all except local
  hosts: all:!local
```

Comment: `hosts: !localhost` probably works too as e.g. `--limit '!dev'` works

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative:

```
- name: Install this only for local dev machine
  pip: name=pyramid
  delegate_to: localhost
```