# Where should I be organizing host-specific files/templates?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to organize my playbooks according to the [Directory Layout](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) structure. The documentation doesn't seem to have a recommendation for host-specific files/templates.

I have 2 plays for a single site

- example.com-provision.yml
- example.com-deploy.yml

These files are located in the root of my structure. The provisioning playbook simply includes other roles

```yaml
---
- hosts: example.com

  roles:
    - common
    - application
    - database

  become: true
  become_method: su
  become_user: root
```

The deployment playbook doesn't include roles, but has it's own `vars` and `tasks` sections. I have a couple `template` and `copy` tasks, and am wondering what the 'best practice' is for where to put these host-specific templates/files within this directory structure.

Right now I have them at `./roles/example.com/templates/` and `./roles/example.com/files/`, but need to reference the files with their full path from my deployment playbook, like

```yaml
- name: deployment | copy httpd config
  template:
    src: ./roles/example.com/templates/{{ host }}.conf.j2
    # ...
```

instead of

```yaml
- name: deployment | copy httpd config
  template:
    src: {{ host }}.conf.j2
    # ...
```

Comment: depends on how you are handling dynamic inventory, too. i believe the smallest scope you should consider is roles or groups versus hosts. if your templates are different for types of hosts then maybe they are different roles. that also depends on the content of your templates.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Facing the same problem the cleanest way seems for me the following structure:

In the top-level directory (same level as playbooks) I have a `files` folder (and if I needed also a `templates` folder). In the `files` folder there is a folder for every host with it's own files where the folder's name is the same as the host name in inventory.
(see the structure below: `myhost1` `myhost2`)

```
.
├── files
│   ├── common
│   ├── myhost1
│   ├── myhost2
|
├── inventory
│   ├── group_vars
│   └── host_vars
├── roles
│   ├── first_role
│   └── second_role
└── my_playbook.yml
```

Now in any role you can access the files with files modules relatively:

```yaml
# ./roles/first_role/main.yml

- name: Copy any host based file
  copy:
    src: "{{ inventory_hostname }}/file1"
    dest: /tmp
```

**Explanation**:

The magic variable `inventory_hostname` is to get the host, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346390/how-to-get-the-host-name-of-the-current-machine-as-defined-in-the-ansible-hosts)
The any `file` module (as for example `copy`) looks up the `files` directory in the respective role directory **and** the `files` directory in the same level as the calling playbook. Of course same applies to templates (but if you have different templates for the same role you should reconsider your design)

Semantically a host specific file does not belong into a role, but somewhere outside (like `host_vars`).

Comment: I decided to go a slightly different route based on this answer. I now have a directory for each host off of the root of my provisioning project's structure. I have a `files/`, `group_vars/`, and `templates/` directory in each of these host directories, and refer to them with a relative `../templates/...` style path - equally simple to your `{{ inventory_hostname }}` approach. Thanks for the bump in the right direction.

Comment: Followed a simlar path, allowed for the src to be filtered with a default, and when defined at playbook level ( it can also use the group/hostname ) and follow that path under the global ansible/templates folder