# Ansible deploy security certificates to remote servers

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'm a bit stumped on an Ansible issue. I've gotten a portion of my setup script working for my database servers, and I would like Ansible to be able to manage each server's postgresql.conf file. I currently have it pushing out an up-to-date copy of the config file, but this has presented a problem.

Our security certificates are unique to each server, and the postgresql.conf has parameters  for setting these up for each server. I've currently got Ansible calculating the proper initial values for things like shared_buffers and effective_cache_size, but do not know how to get it to push a unique certificate out to each remote server, or to uniquely set the name in the config file to match the certificate name.

Are these even possible with Ansible?

Comment: could you format this into a proper question?

Comment: you should use [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) module

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement recently to deploy a specific file (Java keystore) per host, along with the relevant keystore password to decrypt and use it.

For the per-host keystore password, I used host_vars: inside the group host file `inventory/demoGroupName/hosts`:

```
hostname1.com keystore_password="{{ vault_keystore_password_hostname1.com }}"
hostname2.com keystore_password="{{ vault_keystore_password_hostname2.com }}"
```

and then in `inventory/demoGroupName/vault`:

```
vault_keystore_password_hostname1.com=superSecurePassword
vault_keystore_password_hostname2.com=nonRepeatedPassword
```

(Note: the use of vault_ as a prefix is recommended in [Ansible's best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#variables-and-vaults), but feel free to modify this to suit your scenario)

and then in the job, simply place {{ keystore_password }} in the relevant spot, as an example:

```
- name: arbitrary tasks
  command: configure-keystore --password="{{ keystore_password }}"
```

Now in my scenario, I placed the individual keystores into the roles/role_name/files directory and copied it across by substituting in the {{ inventory_hostname }} as part of the filename, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830428/where-should-i-be-organizing-host-specific-files-templates) answer gives a better solution in my opinion. Either will work for your situation, but the latter is *probably* better long-term. If the name of the certificate can be made the same for all hosts, that will also simplify your situation somewhat.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I'll need.