# Non ansible files treated as ansible configuration files

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have this ansible inventory structure:

```
inventory/
  group_vars/
  host_vars/
    /my_host1/
    /my_host2/
      aws/
        config
        credentials
      some.conf
```

When I run ansible playbook, I get this error:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected <document start>

The error appears to be in '/home/user/src/my-ansible/inventory/host_vars/my_host2/aws/config': line 2, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

[default]
region = eu-central-1
^ here
```

It tries to read `config` file in `aws` directory as YAML host config file. If I rename it to something like `config.txt`, it then ignores it.

Is there a way to make sure ansible would recognize this as simple file, instead of trying to read it as some sort of ansible config? Or I should just specify `.conf` and be done with it?

Comment: Which playbook are your running? From which directory? Using which exact command?

Comment: @Zeitounator For example `ansible-playbook workflows/playbooks/deploy-stage.yml -e "target=my_host2" --skip-tags=restore`. Its run from my ansible project root dir. Where it has inventory dir and workflows dir (playbooks with roles).

Comment: Other question: what are configuration files not related to ansible inventory doing inside your ansible inventory? It looks like your main problem. They should be in a `files` or `templates` dir adjacent to you playbook or inside a role.

Comment: @Zeitounator why should I put sensitive/config data inside playbook or role? I am reusing playbooks and roles for other projects. And I keep sensitive/configuration data in inventory that is related with specific host. Isn't thats where you supposed to keep it? And why you think they are not related with inventory?

Comment: `And why you think they are not related with inventory?` <= because ansible is trying to read them and they are not supposed to be read. Using hidden folders as proposed below can do the trick. But the best practice would be to put only files that can be read with `ansible-inventory`. Files to be reused/copied do not belong in inventory. Note that I proposed to use `files` and `templates` folders which is exactly what you accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually stated in the documentation:

> You can also create directories named after your groups or hosts. Ansible will read all the files in these directories in lexicographical order.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables*</sup>

So, because your config file is a file in a format Ansible will consider: either no extension, or optionally end in *.yml*, *.yaml*, or *.json*, the file *inventory/host_vars/my_host2/aws/config* is parsed as a variable file.

I would recommend you to store your host specific files in another location than under their host variables folder, probably the best idea would be under the *files* directory of your playbook.
See: [Where should I be organizing host-specific files/templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830428/where-should-i-be-organizing-host-specific-files-templates)

---

Another idea would be to make your aws folder an hidden folder:

```
└── inventories
    └── host_vars
        └── my_host2
            └── .aws
                └── config
```

This way, the folder won't be parsed by Ansible.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't know there was `files` directory (per host) that ansible can look up.