# Equivalent of "self" in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I've got a hosts file for multiplexing in Ansible

```
[masters]
master ansible_host=10.10.1.1 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=froyo 

[workers]
worker1 ansible_host=10.10.1.2 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=froyo
worker2 ansible_host=10.10.1.3 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=froyo
```

and I'm wanting to make a shell command to set node names

```
- hosts: workers
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: join cluster
      shell: "{{ hostvars['master'].join_command }} --node-name {{self.name}} >> node_joined.txt"
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
        creates: node_joined.txt
```

The Q/A in [How to get the host name of the current machine as defined in the Ansible hosts file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346390/how-to-get-the-host-name-of-the-current-machine-as-defined-in-the-ansible-hosts) identified to include `inventory_hostname`, however this did not work for me .. I could change the hostnames of the workers, which is what I want to avoid.

from the above play i'm expecting two nodes to be identified in master via the names `worker1` and `worker2` that exist in the `hosts` file.

i couldn't set anything: `inventory_hostname` or others including `ansible_hostname` and `ansible_nodename`. is there any way to access the names `worker1` and `worker2` from the hosts? it doesn't seem the variables from `ansible -i hosts worker1 -m setup`  can be set... please help me identify what i'm missing, thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

You need to limit the playbook to worker1

Try:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts --limit worker1 -m setup`